# ffmpeg text overlay both ${frame_num} and :timecode values?

Tags: ffmpeg

Text overlay does not work if `framenum 1..n` and `timecode hh:mm:ss:frame` attributes are used together, how do overlay both running values?

```
Does not work, only timecode is incrementing and framenum is a as a text:
ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -nostats ^
  -i "video_25fps.mp4" -threads 4 -preset fast ^
  -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level 4.0 -s:v 640x360 -b:v 512k -pix_fmt yuv420p ^
  -refs 3 -bf 3 -g 50 -keyint_min 25 -b_strategy 1 -flags +cgop -sc_threshold 0 ^
  -movflags "negative_cts_offsets+faststart" ^
  -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf:fontcolor=White:fontsize=38:box=1:boxcolor=black:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=text_h-line_h+60:text='H264\ 640x360\ 512k\ frame\: %{frame_num}\ ':start_number=1:timecode=00\\:00\\:00\\:00:rate=25" ^
  -an -sn -t 30 -y output.mp4

Works if framenum only:
  -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf:fontcolor=White:fontsize=38:box=1:boxcolor=black:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=text_h-line_h+60:text='H264\ 640x360\ 512k\ frame\: %{frame_num}':start_number=1"

Works if timecode only:
  -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf:fontcolor=White:fontsize=38:box=1:boxcolor=black:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=text_h-line_h+60:text='H264\ 640x360\ 512k\ ':timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=25"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double up on the `drawtext` instruction, separating them with a comma.

i.e.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='Frame\: %{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh):font='Noto mono':fontsize=40:alpha=0.5:box=1:boxborderw=4,drawtext=text='':x=(w-tw)/2:y=(lh):fontsize=40:fontcolor=white:timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':timecode_rate=25" -c:a copy output2.mp4
```

[image]